# Deriving $R^2$ from $R$

Tags: correlation, linear-regression

I got stuck on a seemingly very simple problem while revising my notes on linear regression. More specifically with deriving $R^2$ from $R$.

Wikipedia page for [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) starts the derivation of $R^2$ as such:

$$
R = \frac{\sum (y-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y})}
         {\sqrt{\sum (y-\bar{y})^{2}\cdot \sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}}
  = \ldots
  = \sqrt{\frac{\sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}{\sum (y-\bar{y})^{2}}}
$$

And this is where I got stuck. If I take both sides (left and right of $=\ldots=$) of the above equation, square them and simplify a bit, I get this:

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\sum (y-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y})}
     {\sqrt{\sum (y-\bar{y})^{2}\cdot \sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}}
 &=\sqrt{\frac{\sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}{\sum (y-\bar{y})^{2}}} \\
\frac{(\sum (y-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y}))^{2}}
     {\sum (y-\bar{y})^{2}\cdot \sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}
 &=\frac{\sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}{\sum (y-\bar{y})^{2}} \\
\frac{(\sum (y-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y}))^{2}}
     {\sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2}}
 &=\sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2} \\
(\sum (y-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y}))^2 &= (\sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})^{2})^{2} \\
\sum (y-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y}) &= \sum (\hat{y}-\bar{y})(\hat{y}-\bar{y})
\end{split}
$$

Doesn't this imply that $y=\hat{y}$? Makes no sense. Can you spot the mistake?

Thanks
Edvin

Comment: No, it just means that the mean of $y$ is equal to the mean of $\hat{y}$.

Comment: Thank you! All clear now.